# How to loop through fieldset to check if controls are empty or values not selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple fieldsets(5 at the moment, but will grow) and I want to loop through each element within each fieldset for validation purposes:

Inputs/TextAreas(Textboxes): Check if empty.

Selects(Dropdowns): Check if value is 0.

Here are 3 of my Fieldsets:

```
    <!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset style="max-width:400px;">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 1</h3>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @type = "email",@id = "email",  @name = "email", @placeholder="Email", @required = "*", @class = "form-control input-lg" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @type = "password", @class = "form-control input-lg", @id = "password", @placeholder="Password", @required = "*" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @type = "password", @class = "form-control input-lg", @id = "confirmpassword", @placeholder = "Confirm Password", @required = "*" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="max-width:400px;">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Upload your CV</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 2</h3>
    <input type="file" name="file" placeholder="Upload file" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="max-width:400px;">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 3</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
    @*<textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>*@
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

PLEASE NOTE: The first fieldset is different as I am busy changing the Inputs ect. to make use of Models within MVC, but it ultimately comes down to the same thing.

Below is my JavaScript within a .js file to move to the next fieldset(think of this process as a wizard, or for registration):

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
    'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
    'position': 'absolute'
  });
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to validate on click of next button

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $("fieldset").children().not("h2, h3, button").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
    alert("Empty!!")
    }
    })
})
```

To skip the elements which needs not to validate use not().

Comment: Thanks. This does pretty much what I want it to do. Appreciate the assistance!